# \$G_m\$ is zero in my calculation when doing gain analysis, what went wrong?

Tags: gain

The following is from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), page 147.

[image]

In order to calculate this \$R_{out}\$.

The following is the analysis for \$R_{out}\$ calculation.

[image]

$$\frac{V_p} {r_{o1}} + V_p g_{m1} = (- V_p) g_{m2} + \frac{V_T - V_p} {r_{o2}}$$

$$I_T = \frac{V_p} {r_{o1}} + V_p g_{m1} + \frac{V_T} {r_{o4}}$$

Assume the following for \$r_{d1}\$ , \$r_{d2}\$
$$r_{d1} = g_{m1} \parallel \frac{1} {r_{o1}} $$
$$r_{d2} = g_{m2} \parallel \frac{1} {r_{o2}} $$

We will have
$$R_{out} = \frac{V_T} {I_T} = \frac{r_{o2} r_{o4} (r_{d1} + r_{d2})} {r_{d2} r_{o4} + r_{o2} (r_{d1} + r_{d2})} $$

According to @G36, \$r_{d1} = r_{d2}\$.

$$R_{out} = \frac{r_{o2} r_{o4} (r_{d1} + r_{d2})} {r_{d2} r_{o4} + r_{o2} (r_{d1} + r_{d2})} = \frac{2 r_d r_{o2} r_{o4}} {r_{d} r_{o4} + 2 r_{o2} r_{d}} = \frac{2  r_{o2} r_{o4}} { r_{o4} + 2 r_{o2}} = (2 r_{o2}) \parallel r_{o4}$$

However, Why does the book assume \$r_{d1} \approx r_{o1} \$ and  \$r_{d2} \approx r_{o2} \$? book said this following

$$R_{out} = 2 r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4}  $$

For calculation about \$G_m\$.

[image]

[image]

$$I_{out} = (V_{in} - V_p) g_{m2} - \frac{V_p} {r_{o2}}$$

$$(V_{in} - V_p) g_{m2} - \frac{V_p} {r_{o2}} = -(V_{in} - V_p) g_{m1} + \frac{V_p} {r_{o1}}$$

$$\Rightarrow V_p = \frac{V_{in} (g_{m1} + g_{m2})} {g_{m1} + 1/r_{o1} + g_{m2} + 1/r_{o2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow I_{out} = V_{in} \frac{ g_{m2}/r_{o1} - g_{m1}/r_{o2}} {g_{m1} + 1/r_{o1} + g_{m2} + 1/r_{o2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow G_{m} = \frac{I_{out}} {V_{in}} = \frac{ g_{m2}/r_{o1} - g_{m1}/r_{o2}} {g_{m1} + 1/r_{o1} + g_{m2} + 1/r_{o2}}$$

According to @G36 \$r_{o1} = r_{o2} = r_o, g_{m1} = g_{m2} = g_{m}\$.

$$\Rightarrow G_{m} = 0$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150474/discussion-on-question-by-kile-g-m-is-zero-in-my-calculation-when-doing-gain); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.