# Failed to simulate active current mirror in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, differential-amplifier

The following is my schematic for active current mirror:

[image]

This is a SPICE simulation for my [old question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/695015/g-m-is-zero-in-my-calculation-when-doing-gain-analysis-what-went-wrong):

The following is the \$V_{out}\$ plot.

[image]

What's wrong with my \$V_{out}\$?

The asc file is provide here:

```
* G:\LTspice\Active_current_mirror_Amplifier.asc
I1 N007 0 100µ
V1 N001 0 5
Vin+ N004 0 SINE(0 10m 1Meg)
Vin- N006 0 SINE(0 -10m 1Meg) AC 1
C2 N003 Vout 10µ
M1 N001 N005 N007 0 NMOS l=1u w=176u
M2 N003 N005 N007 0 NMOS l=1u w=176u
M3 N001 N002 N003 N001 PMOS l=10u w=10u
M4 N001 N002 N002 N001 PMOS l=10u w=10u
I2 N002 0 50µ
R1 N001 N005 8Meg
R2 N005 0 2Meg
C1 N005 N004 10µ
C3 N006 N005 10µ
.model NMOS NMOS
.model PMOS PMOS
.lib C:\Users\jackh\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.mos
.tran 0 1000u 990u 10m
.MODEL nmos nmos(kp=200u,vto=0.4, lambda = 0.1)
.MODEL pmos pmos(kp=200u,vto=-0.4, lambda =0.05)
;.op
;.ac lin 1000 1 1Meg
.meas Vo pp V(vout);
.meas Vi pp V(n004) - V(n005);
.meas Av param Vo/Vi
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: Try real P and NMOS models with instead of the default ones. Try ramping up the current sources.

Comment: @winny I have tried ramping up the current source. But it's in vain

Comment: @C__ I doubt spice will accept \$\mu\$.

Comment: I'm struggling why you think this is an issue. I think it would be obvious to say that the output voltage is seeing a very small difference in voltage amplitude because there's probably cyclical capacitive voltage activity. Having an output margin of roughly +/- 0.13uV seems like an insignificant issue. **So my question to you is: why are you concerned about Vo?** If your goal was to create a differential op amp, then I'd say you created a rather balanced device.

Comment: @C__ The book of razavi   Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf, page 147 give me this circuit. See fig 5.23 b

Comment: Doesn’t M2’s gate need its own 8meg/2meg divider? I don’t think it’s valid to tie M1 and M2 gates together.

Comment: This is a tutorial on MOSFET active current mirror in LTspice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhxlIkNxnw4 you can take a look. You can also post your question to this forum: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Solar_LED_Heart_Ornament.html  There are any LTspice users here.

Comment: @SteKulov You're right. I modified according to your hints, it works now! Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a wire shorting the inputs from the positive and negative sources in your circuit:

[image]

Since both sources `Vin+` and `Vin-` are driving the circuit through identical 10 uF capacitors, the voltage signal at the gate node (the node connected to the gates of M1 and M2) is going to have essentially 0 amplitude, and therefore the sources are not going to affect the circuit at all. So it's no surprise there's no response at `Vout`.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. Do you mean \$V_{g1} = V_{g2}\$ even in AC analysis?

Comment: Yes, in SPICE a short circuit forces all connected terminals to exactly the same voltage in any analysis at any frequency.

Comment: .... a short circuit does that in real life  Spice is just simulating that

Comment: @ReversedEngineer, real "short circuits" have inductance and resistance. At some high frequency or high current there is a detectable difference in voltage between the two ends. SPICE short circuits are a mathematical assertion that two terminals are connected to the identical voltage (and only one variable exists in the nodal equations to represent that voltage).

Comment: @ThePhoton Sure, you're absolutely right! I actually implied that in my original comment, then deleted and recreated the comment to simplify it. Didn't seem to be relevant to the issue in question here.